# How to make good quality onion powder at home?

Tags: onions, seasoning, powder

I chopped some onion and put it in an old gas oven. It had 3 issues:

1. Some pieces or parts of pieces are burned while other pieces are
   still not dehydrated.
2. It sticks with the bottom of the aluminum plate.
3. It has a bitter taste.

How can I solve the 3 issues to produce high quality onion powder at home?

[image]

Comment: An oven isn't a very good dehydrator: it's too hot and not enough air circulation. Dehydrators are pretty cheap, and it's not hard to make your own with something like a space heater and a fan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's likely that your oven, even on the coolest setting, is too hot. That's why the onion burnt, and the bitterness comes from the burnt bits.

I occasionally use my electric oven for dehydrating fruit and veg but mine goes down to 50°C. I tend to preheat it to about 100°C and turn it down when the food had been in for a few minutes, at which point I open the door as well.

A gas oven has another problem - burning gas produces water vapour, which makes drying harder even with ventilation (you really do need the door ajar to let the steam out). Drying on a rack (borrowed from a grill pan, or a cake cooling rack) makes a huge difference.

I also have a dehydrator, but it's not all that  much better than the oven for a small batch in winter, so I leave it stored away except when I've got a lot to dry. It wins on capacity and the fact I can run it outside - worthwhile for chillies and presumably onions.

Comment: All very well put. Drying chilies indoors is absolutely awful.

Comment: @GdD A mistake you should only make once, but I made it twice: first in the oven then in the dehydrator. Now I run it ouside on a nice the sun helps with the drying.